# iOS: How to retrieve image dimensions X, Y from CGContextRef

Tags: ios, bitmap, size, extract, cgcontext

As it says on the can;  here is an example of why I need it:

Let's say I create a bitmap context:

```
size_t pixelCount = dest_W * dest_H;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t r,g,b,a;
} RGBA;

// backing bitmap store
RGBA* pixels = calloc( pixelCount, sizeof( RGBA ) );

// create context using above store
CGContextRef X_RGBA;
{
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = dest_W * sizeof( RGBA );

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create a context with RGBA pixels
    X_RGBA = CGBitmapContextCreate( (void *)pixels, dest_W, dest_H, 
                                   bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, 
                                   colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
                                   );        
    assert(X_RGBA);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Now I want to throw this context to a drawing function that will eg draw a circle touching the edges:

Do I really need to throw in the width and height as well?   I am 99% sure I have seen some way to extract the width and height from the context, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CGBitmapContextGetWidth // and Height
```

NB width and height probably don't make sense to a non-bitmap CGContextRef

Thanks @ wiliz on #iphonedev